# Geolocation location changes

Tags: html, geolocation

Over the last few days I've been working on a project involving geolocation in HTML5 and I've become familiar with the concept. [This demo](http://html5demos.com/geo) as well as a similar example that forms part of my project has always been accurate in determining my location to a few hundred metres. However, as of just now they all plot me as being in the nearest large city. For my project it is important that the location remains constant - what could have prompted this?

Comment: Do you even know how this works?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, everything's remained constant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Location information can be sourced from GPS and location inferred from network signals such as IP address, RFID, WiFi and Bluetooth MAC addresses, and GSM/CDMA cell IDs, as well as user input.

It depends on what device you're testing and where it is sourcing geolocation data from. IP address lookups may change as databases are constantly updated, or a shared IP address will change depending on user input from other users. An accurate GPS fix may not be available right now. Your device temporarily switched cell towers. Etc...

Comment: Also just to state the obvious - don't rely too heavily on geolocation data. It currently shows me in Birmingham Magistrate Court, but I hid the court summons and never went.

Comment: I see, sounds very complicated indeed! Just confused because I'm using the same machine/browser/connection as before, and I've been moved by almost 10 miles!

Comment: @Sebastian What device are you using? How is it connected to the Internet?

Comment: It's an iMac connected to a router and my browser is Chrome.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest it's getting your location from your IP address. It might be that your IP address is dynamic (changes each time you connect to the Internet), or shared (and another user on your IP address reported their location in the centre of town). Either way it is almost definitely queried through Google Location Services. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's given me a lot to look into as geolocation is an important part of my project.

Answer (score 0):

If accuracy is your primary concern then use [`watchPosition`](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#watch-position) instead of `getCurrentPosition` and monitor the [`accuracy`](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#accuracy) of the returned position, only update when that drops below your threshold.